# USB keyboard does not work on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, usb, keyboard, dell

**My laptop model:** Dell N4110

**OS:** Ubuntu 11.10

I have brought a USB keyboard and plugged into my laptop. But it does not work. Please suggest me what should I do?

Comment: You would need to tell us more , what keyboard ? IMO, if you recently bought it, and it does not work, probably easier to exchange it and try an alternate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try plugging in a USB flash drive or USB mouse. If this is recognized, it means your USB ports are working well, and the most likely cause is that the keyboard is defective.

If the flash drive or mouse don't work, it may mean your USB ports aren't working correctly.

Try different ports on your computer to see if they all fail or only one of them does.